# PHP Gradient Issues

Tags: php, gradient

I'm currently using a php class for text gradients. (Mainly used for usernames) However i'm having a issue with it, I have added a screenshot to show what happens:

[image: Screenshot gradient issues]

The gradient should have ended at:

```
<span style="color: #1a1a1a">g</span>
```

But it seems it's adding more span attributes to it, with weird characters.

I'm currently using this code to make the username:

```
if ($this->gradienttype == 3 && $this->gradientcolours != "" && $this->gradientdays > 0) {

        $colours = explode("~", $this->gradientcolours);

        $gradient = new ColourGradient(array(0 => $colours['0'], floor((strlen($this->username) / 2) - 1) => $colours['1'], (strlen($this->username) - 1) => $colours['2']));

        $this->formattedname .=  "<b><a title='" . $this->title . "' href='/profiles.php?id=" . $this->id . "'>";

        foreach ($gradient as $i => $colour) {
            if(!isset($this->username[$i])) { $this->username[$i] = ''; }
            $this->formattedname .= "<span style='color:" . $colour . "'>" . $this->username[$i] . "</span>";
        }

    }
```

I'm not sure what's causing the weird characters, but I think it has something to do with this:

```
if(!isset($this->username[$i])) { $this->username[$i] = ''; }
```

Because when I remove that the characters are gone, but then I get:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 9 in
```

My question is how do I remove these characters and stop the gradient at the end of the last letter of the name?

If I need to submit the classes to make the gradient I will post them on a pastebin cause they're quite large.

Comment: Try to replace with this if(!isset($this->username[$i])) { continue; }

Comment: Thank you very much @AleksandarPopovic, It works as it should be now. It has no weird characters anymore and it ends at the last letter of the name. Didn't think it was so easy. Many thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace with this

```
if(!isset($this->username[$i])) {
    continue;
}
```

Credits to [Aleksandar Popovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1591143/aleksandar-popovic)